# reactjs remove one by one in shopping cart

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is redux shopping cart program, most popular one. I try to implement with reducing the item number by one.  But I can't. I almost search internet for any help. But only fully removing the item from the cart process is worked out. I need a count type implemention. I hope You all understand my doubt. Here is my code:

```
 const addedIds = (state = initialState.addedIds, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
          if (state.indexOf(action.productId) !== -1) {
            return state
          }
          return [ ...state, action.productId ]

          case REDUCT_FROM_CART:
           return state.filter(productId => action.productId !== productId)
          default:
           return state
      }
    }

    const quantityById = (state = initialState.quantityById, action) => {

      switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
          const{ productId } = action
          return { ...state,
            [productId]: (state[productId] || 0) + 1
          }

          case REDUCT_FROM_CART:

          return {  ...state,
            [productId]: state[productId|| 0] + 1
          } 
          default:
          return state
      }
    }

    export const getQuantity = (state, productId) =>

      state.quantityById[productId] || 0

    export const getAddedIds = state => state.addedIds

    const cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case CHECKOUT_REQUEST:
          return initialState
        case CHECKOUT_FAILURE:
          return action.cart
        default:
          return {
            addedIds: addedIds(state.addedIds, action),
            quantityById: quantityById(state.quantityById, action)
          }
```

Please anyone help me to solve the reduct case. I stucked here because of this issue. Is the above code is right or not? Does any modification needed? Please don't ignore this doubt. I need your kind help.

```
const ProductItem = ({ product, onAddToCartClicked, onReductFromCartClicked }) => (
  <div style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
    <Product
      title={product.title}
      price={product.price}
      quantity={product.inventory}
      image={product.image} />
  <div className="product__button-wrap">
    <button
      className={ADD_TO_CART ? 'btn btn-danger' : 'btn btn-primary'}
      onClick={onAddToCartClicked}
      disabled={product.inventory > 0 ? '' : 'disabled'}>
      {product.inventory > 0 ? 'Add to cart' : 'Sold Out'}
    </button>
    <button 
      className={REDUCT_FROM_CART ? 'btn btn-danger' : 'btn btn-primary'}
      onClick={onReductFromCartClicked}
      disabled={product.inventory < 0 ? 'disabled' :'' }>
      {product.inventory < 0 ? 'No Item' : 'Reduct from cart' }
    </button>
    </div>

  </div>
)
```

And this is the productitem page. I hope I'll get the solved code with the help of yours...

[image: Here is my console screen]
[image: This is my webpage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
          const{ productId } = action
          const newState1 = { ...state,
            [productId]: (state[productId] || 0) + 1
          }
          console.log("---- After ADD:");
          console.log("- oldState: ");
          console.log(state);
          console.log("productId: ", productId);
          console.log("- newState: ");
          console.log(newState1);
          return newState1;

          case REDUCT_FROM_CART:

          const newState2 {  ...state,
            [productId]: state[productId] - 1
          } 
          console.log("---- After REDUCT:");
          console.log("- oldState: ");
          console.log(state);
          console.log("productId: ", productId);
          console.log("- newState2: ");
          console.log(newState2 );
          return newState2 ;

          default:
          return state
      }
```

Comment: sorry the doesn't change.. I also tried this code ...No change.. What will I do?

Comment: Updated. please add to your question the output from console.log .

Comment: Should be something like: https://learning-services-media.brightcove.com/doc-assets/video-cloud-apis/general-information/debugging-basics/console-log-demo.png

Comment: I updated the code, added more console.log() calls. I am looking for the console.log from chrome. Run the code in chrome.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to run my code in chrome.. If you never mind tell  me how to run.. Thank you.

Comment: How did you create your app? Did you use create-react-app? If so, you run npm start in your cmd window (assuming that you use windows) and go to http://localhost:3000/

Comment: OO yeah..  In chrome  I got my webpage. But the reduct button doen't work... I will show  a screenshot my page

Comment: I added a screenshot above

Comment: I don't understand what is displayed in your console.log(). This is not what I am used to see... I think that I give up... No more time. Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Your REDUCT_FROM_CART action needs to decrease the quantity but you are adding 1 to it. alsso you have a syntax error there

```
const quantityById = (state = initialState.quantityById, action) => {

      switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
          const{ productId } = action
          return { ...state,
            [productId]: (state[productId] || 0) + 1
          }

          case REDUCT_FROM_CART:

          return {  ...state,
            [productId]: state[productId] - 1
          } 
          default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't change.. I also tried this code ...No change.. What will I do?

Comment: can you log and check if the reducer is getting called or not

Comment: I am not sure what exactly to look for. Can you specify what exact problem are you facing,

Comment: actually I got my program output as shown as above but without the reduct feature

Comment: can you add onReductFromCartClicked action creator and make sure that the redux action is being called